# Using for loop to store text of TextView

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, textview, onrestoreinstancestate

I am trying to store the text inside many TextViews to restore in a new Activity and I would like to know how can I do this using a for loop instead of doing one by one.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    String item1;
    String item2;
    String item3;
    if (listItem1!=null){
        item1 = listItem1.getText().toString();
        outState.putString(TEXT_SAVED, item1);
    }
    if (listItem2!=null){
        item2 = listItem2.getText().toString();
        outState.putString(TEXT_SAVED, item2);
    }
    if (listItem3!=null){
        item3 = listItem3.getText().toString();
        outState.putString(TEXT_SAVED, item3);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your values of your `listItem`s via reflection. In this given example you need to replace `Data` by the class your `listItem`s are from. You need for this example the getters for your listItems, e.g.

```
public Data getListItem1() {
    return listItem1;
}
```

Via the line starting with Method method you are getting the `Getter` dynamic from the current index in the `for`-loop. In the next line, the method (in this case, the `Getter`
is called and the value of this method call is returned. Please be aware that reflection is causing the following exceptions: `IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException  |SecurityException`. These exceptions need to be handeld in case something went wrong.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getListItem" + i);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Data data = (Data) method.invoke(this);
        if(data != null) {
            String value = data.getText().toString();
            outState.putString(TEXT_SAVED, value);
        }
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Another possible solution would be to store all your listItems in a `java.util.List` and looping over it.